# Как создать страничку с заголовками и кратким описанием новостей?

Tags: php, html

Вопрос такой: Как создать страничку с заголовками и кратким описанием новостей, как на большинстве сайтов что бы например на этой странице выводилось по 10 статей с кратким описанием а потом нужно было перейти на другую страницу и там еще 10 статей, знаю что вопрос глупый но подскажите хотя бы в какую сторону копать это фреймворки или еще что то, PHP только начал изучать, но бегло пролистал пару книг ответа на свой вопрос в них не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю проще всего использовать какой-нибудь движок. Исходя из того, что вы написали вам подходит WordPress. Тут минимум программирования, скорее больше администрирование.

Если хочется написать самому, тогда вам нужно:

1. Выбрать СУБД. Подойдёт Mysql, потому что она бесплатная и в интернете достаточно много информации о ней.
2. разработать структуру базы данных, которая будет хранить ваши новости/статьи
3. Написать скрипт, который будет брать данные из БД и отображать превью статей. В качестве одного из параметров запроса скрипта - страница. Ее нужно передавать в запрос к БД, чтобы получить нужные данные. Ответ от БД нужно обработать и вывести ввиде html кода. Это можно сделать вручную или с помощью шаблонизатора, например (Jinja, Volt)
4. Написать скрипт, который отображает статью полностью. Скрипт должен принимать на вход идентификатор статьи, делать запрос к БД, обрабатывать результат и выводить его в виде html. Опять же вручную или с использованием шаблонов

Есть еще микрофреймворк Phalcon. Он содержит в себе средства работы с БД, есть встроенный шаблонизатор Volt, а также имеет документацию на русском языке. Подробнее: http://docs.phalconphp.ru